# can anyone help me convert this to react-router v6 writing method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const DishWithId = ({match}) => {
      return(
          <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))[0]} 
            comments={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))} />
      );
    };
    
. . .

              <Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={DishWithId} />
```

am trying to convert react-router v5 to react-router v6 and am stuck on this part I have tried to use useParams by importing it from react-rout-dom   but it is not working

```
const DishWithId = ({match}) => {

        let params =useParams()

        return(
            <DishDetail dish={DISHES.filter((dish) =>  dish.id ===  parseInt(params.dishId,10))[0]} 
              comments={COMMENTS.filter((comment) =>  comment.dishId ===  parseInt(params.dishId,10) )} />
              
        );
      }
```

Comment: You didn't even share how your route/url looks like

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please clarify.

Comment: did not able to identify what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem also,  but this is how I solved mine.

*1. first import useParams from react-router-dom.

*2. replcace the function as shown:

const DishWithId = () => {
const { dishId } = useParams();
return (
<DishDetails
dish={
this.state.dishes.filter(
(dish) => dish.id === parseInt(dishId, 10)
)[0]
}
comments={this.state.comments.filter(
(comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(dishId, 10)
)}
/>
);

Comment: This is helpful information. It will be easier to read if you place your code sample in markdown code fencing so it is automatically formatted. 

```js
const myCode = code()
```